# which of the following random variable is continuous

Tags: probability, statistics

on a quiz made ​​to any contestant 5 consecutive questions. Has in his possession  20 seconds to answer before proceeding to the next question. if he answer correctly before the 20 seconds recorded the time taken. if the  20 seconds pass without the correct answer recorded 20 seconds. the competition involved 50 50 contestants. winner is whoever have the lowest total time for the 5 Questions. which of the following random variable is continuous:
1) the maximum number of correct answers given by a contestant
2) the multitude of correct answers given by the contestant who asked first
3) the number of contestnts with a total time of 5 Questions for less than 40 seconds
4) The minimum time that was recorded for a correct answer to Question

Comment: Is it a homework?

Comment: -1.  Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** any random variable which can only take integer values has a discrete distribution and not continuous.